# How to dynamically inspect a GenericAlias (Type) object to determine the types it contains?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a dataclass with typed `tuple` fields, and I'd like to dynamically see the types of their elements. When I print the types, I see them as containers (whose contents are exactly what I want):

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class TupleContainer:
    tuple2: tuple[float, str]
    tuple1: tuple[int, ...]


for field in fields(TupleContainer):
    t = field.type
    print(repr(t)) 

    # prints:
    # tuple[float, str]
    # tuple[int, ...]
```

but when I try to iterate through or index into `t` I get `TypeError: 'types.GenericAlias' object is not iterable` or `TypeError: There are no type variables left in tuple[float, str]`.

It really seems like this ought to be possible, but I've had no luck reading the PEPs or docs.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_args

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`__args__` was what I wanted!

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, fields

@dataclass
class TupleContainer:
    tuple2: tuple[float, str]
    tuple1: tuple[int, ...]


for field in fields(TupleContainer):
    t = field.type
    print(repr(t))
    print(t.__args__)
```

prints:

```
tuple[float, str]
(<class 'float'>, <class 'str'>)
tuple[int, ...]
(<class 'int'>, Ellipsis)
```

Comment: Prefer `typing.get_args` helper for this to avoid using dunder attributes directly.